# Setting up ssh config file for multiple Codebase accounts

Tags: git, ssh, codebase

The agency I work for have a Codebase account that I sometimes need to work with at home, but I have just setup a Codebase account for my freelance work, too.

However, I keep getting permission errors when pushing up to the repo because my ssh config file now has two codebasehq.com hosts to point to.

How can I set this up so I can pull & push to two separate repos on two separate accounts?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Thanks! `ssh-add ~/.ssh/work_rsa` was the command I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.

The format for the alias entries use in this example is:

> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName <host1> 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```

To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName <host1>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName <host2>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

## PS

Don't forget to load the keys to your server.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that both of the Hostnames are codebasehq.com and they're both pointing towards their separate Identiyfiles yet I can't seem to push to the work one since I've setup my personal one this evening.
Thanks though!

Comment: I had this side of it all set up correctly, I just had to use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/work_rsa` to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Sure np. tying to help. you can also do this: `eval $(ssh-agent)`